# How can I get the name with the ID ? Or sort them?

Tags: php, json, get, decode

I got this big problem,and I can't find a solution..
I got this Json being returned to me from an API,but I don't really know how can I get the name of the hero by using his id ?

```
[
{ "id":0, "name":"N/A"  },
{ "id":1, "name":"John" },
{ "id":2, "name":"Doom" }
]
```

Tried something like :

```
$data = json_decode($json,true); 
$id = $data[0]['id'];
$name = $data[0][$id]['name'];
```

But I can't really make this work...
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You have to loop on your $data and add condition for checking hero id you'll get the name

Comment: Check my answer, I have tested it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your example you are looking to get index '0' in the JSON array, index 0 would be:

```
{ "id":0, "name":"N/A"  }
```

This index 0 is now a key-value pair so you can simply call

```
$id = $data[0]['id'];
$name = $data[0]['name'];
```

If you wanted to do it for all of the elements in the array then you could use a for-loop or a foreach-loop.

To get the name for the ID you would have to do something like the following:

```
function name_for_id($data, $id) {

  foreach ($data as $value) {

    if ($value['id'] == $id)
      return $value['name'];

  }
}
```

See http://pastebin.com/Rtq3NbQd for full code example

Comment: Yes,but how can I get the name,based on the ID ?
I need it to show me the name,based on the ID I give to it...

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6Zyxminm This Is what I need to grab. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

You gotta loop through the array checking the id, and when it's found, retrieve the name. Something like that:

```
function getHeroName($data, $id) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
        if ($data[$i]['id'] == $id) {
            return $data[$i]['name'];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Working Example**

```
<?php
$json = '[{"id":0, "name":"N/A"  },{ "id":1, "name":"John" },{ "id":2, "name":"Doom" }]';
$data = json_decode($json, true); 
$heroId = 1;

foreach($data as $hero) {
    if($hero['id'] == $heroId) {
       echo 'Hero Name :'. $hero['name'];    
    }
}
```